# Angular evaluate expression as if it were in the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for a function that will do something like this in Angular:

```
var testValues = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    number: 15
}
somefunction('Hello, {{name}}, you are {{number}} years old', testValues)
// returns 'Hello, John Doe, you are 15 years old'
```

I know $eval does something similar to this, but it cannot have double braces inside of it.

Comment: Try `$compile()`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service.

Example from the documentation:

```
var $interpolate = ...; // injected
var exp = $interpolate('Hello {{name | uppercase}}!');
expect(exp({name:'Angular'})).toEqual('Hello ANGULAR!');
```

`$interpolate` compiles a string just like in the templates, and returns a function that outputs a string using the provided context.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually compile a template. Inject the `$compile` service and compile the template against a `$scope` object:

```
$scope.model = {
  name: 'tom'
};

$compile('<div>Hello {{model.name}}</div>')($scope);
```

This will return a jqLite object that is wrapped around a DOM object.

Comment: `$compile` might be a bit of an overkill for a simple string interpolation IMO (if  that is all that OP needs), although it works, too - it actually uses `$interpolate` internally.